# How can I DYNAMICALLY change the color of any VIEW which is already using a SELECTOR xml

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-selector

As an example I have a `selector xml` like this:

**view_round_corner_with_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
 <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" 
         android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
 <stroke 
     android:color="@color/black"
     android:width="1dp"/>

 <solid 
     android:color="@color/primary_color"/>
 </shape>
```

In the above `selector` I have defined the background color as **primary_color**. Now What I want to do is, I have to apply this selector which will make round corner to multiple **EditText** and **TextView** **with different color background**. But the problem is, if I use the above selector it will make the background as **primary_color** only and I want different background color.

**If I change the color dynamically like:**

```
editText.setBackgroundResource(R.color.anyColor);
```

then the selector state would get affected and **editText** won't remain with round corners edges.

> What I have done for now is to make multiple selector with different
>   color and use them depending on the logic for multiple **EditText**
>   and **TextView**.

So is there any thing by which I can use the single selector which can be used for multiple **EditText** and **TextView** to dynamically change the background color without affecting there round corners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
Drawable background = textView.getBackground();
if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
   ((ShapeDrawable)background).getPaint().
       setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.anycolor));
} else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
   ((GradientDrawable)background).
       setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.anycolor));
}
```

Comment: Let me check and reply you back.

Comment: I have changed the code the way you suggested but not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using below code:

```
GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) statusTextView
                            .getBackground();
drawable.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                            R.color.green_color));
```